# Join based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I have long hive query, which has 10 joins and lots of conditions, below is 3 conditions

```
1) If id is not equal to XFG or GHT, use field sid
join ABC_Tables on sid  
join CDE_Tables on sid 
2) If id is equal to XFG or GHT, Tested is null, use field pid
join ABC_Tables on kid 
join CDE_Tables on kid
3) If id is equal to XFG or GHT, Tested is not null, use field pid
join ABC_Tables on kid 
join CDE_Tables on kid
```

What am I doing,

```
select 1 conditions
union all
select 2 conditions
union all
select 3 conditions
```

am I doing right. What is the alternative of above problem.

Comment: Please provide the SQL you have tried with, the structure of your tables, sample data, and expected result for that sample. Note that at first view your condition 2 and 3 look too much alike to be mentioned as separate conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are allowed to be part of `ON` join condition. Equal/not equal to constants are allowed in Hive `( ID!='XFG')and(ID!='GHT')and(a.PID=b.PID)` is allowed join condition.  `a.ID not in ('XFG', 'GHT') and  a.sid=b.sid` also should work:

```
select * 
  from a
   left join b on a.ID not in ('XFG', 'GHT') and  a.sid=b.sid
   left join b on a.ID in ('XFG', 'GHT') and Tested is null and  a.pid=b.pid
```